# Software to translate small business English names into Spanish?

Tags: translation

I need to translate the names of many small businesses (e.g. Main Street Laundromat, 6th Avenue Cafe) in the US from English into Spanish. What software can I use?

Comment: [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com)? [Bing Microsoft Translation](https://translate.bing.com)? Also, what do you mean by 'translate the names...'? Proper names (e.g., "Ray's Cafe, Pharmacy, and Cleaners") should not be translated; generic business types (e.g., "pharmacy", "dry cleaners", "luncheonette") generally are.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. I understand your concern with proper names, but some proper names that are based on more generic names can be translated.

Comment: What is the purpose of this translation? If you are preparing a business directory, for example, you should _not_ translate even those "generic" proper names; if you are preparing a procedural manual of some sort where you are using examples, it _might_ be appropriate to render the names into the language of the manual.